# PHP mysql query group by two column and count

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as below.

```
-----------------------------------
| subject | ID | date   | status  |
+---------+----+--------+---------+
| S1997   |153 |25/4/19 | Late    |
| S1997   |154 |25/4/19 | Present |
| S1997   |153 |26/4/19 | Present |
| S1997   |154 |26/4/19 | Present |
| S1999   |153 |27/4/19 | Present |
| S1999   |154 |27/4/19 | Late    |
-----------------------------------
```

How do I write a query to get the result as below

```
 ----------------------------------------
 | subject | ID | total attendance| late|
 +---------+----+-----------------+------
 | S1997   |153 |        2        |  1  |
 | S1997   |154 |        2        |  0  |
 | S1999   |153 |        1        |  0  |
 | S1999   |154 |        1        |  1  |
 ----------------------------------------
```

I tried using GROUP BY but I could not get the table as I want above.

Comment: Please describe the desired output. It's difficult to interpret what you want based on table headers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group by and aggregation

```
select subject, id, count(date) as totalattendance, 
       count(case when status='late' then 1 end) as late
from tablename
group by subject, id
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of the answer given by @fa06:

```
SELECT
    subject,
    id,
    COUNT(*) AS `total attendance`,
    SUM(status = 'late') AS late
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    subject,
    id;
```

We can take advantage of MySQL's conditional `SUM` function to avoid using a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by using `COUNT`, `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT subject,ID,COUNT(*) AS `total attendance`,SUM(IF(status = 'Late', 1, 0)) 
AS late 
FROM `tablename` 
GROUP BY subject,ID
```